# Выполнение js кода в spa

Tags: javascript, vue.js, spa

В общем, у меня есть бд, в которой хранится html страница, необходимо при переходе на компонент отрисовывать страницу и выполнять js код в тэге script. Как я понял директива v-html экранирует скрипты и не дает им выполнятся. Или проблема в жизненом цикле приложения?

Comment: может вы будете данные хранить в бд, а визуализацией пусть занимается js, как это и положено?

Comment: @ArchDemon Я это и пытаюсь сделать. Но, как направить скрипты в обработчик js?

Comment: вы пытаетесь сделать обратное. Хранить вёрстку в бд, что делать нежелательно